# How do I look for any lone character in a PHP string and add a period to the end of it?

Tags: php, regex, string

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do.

I have a case where I am getting a query string of `j-doe` and my function changes it to `J Doe`.

How can I then go through that string, detect a lonesome letter (a name initial) and add a period so it outputs like `J. Doe`?

This would need to detect a lonesome letter anywhere in the string, such as changing `Henry J Doe` to `Henry J. Doe`.

Thank you so much in advance!

EDIT: The string is a name from a database, so no need to worry about single letter words.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: what about "A Novel by J Doe"? `A. Novel by J. Doe`? or `I. See Dead People`?

Comment: Try using the substring function and for each character check if there is a blank before and after the current character. If so, add a . // Edit: Be aware of the first and last character

Comment: Be careful. There are a legitimate cases where people may have a single character name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_replace like this:

```
$str = 'Henry J Doe';
$repl = preg_replace('/([A-Z])(?=\s|$)/', '\1.', $str);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/gqVKIG

Comment: And that's it! Thank you! I had no idea where to start with this one, whether to use regex or strlen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$str = 'Henry J Doe';
$newWords = array();
$words = explode(' ', $str);

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (strlen($word) == 1) {
        $word .= '.';
    }

    $newWords[] = $word;
}

$str = implode(' ', $newWords);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Wow ... You have something against regex eh? :)